# how can i plot a country map in react leaflet with name of county, without using geoJSOM

Tags: leaflet, geolocation, visualization, geojson, react-leaflet

i am using react-leaflet and open street map and i want to plot filled maps of a regions by giving region ( country/state ) names as a input so, one way is to keep geoJSON file which includes countries boundary coordinates whose size is more then 30mb.
i want to go with some different approach. or is their any react library which can provides boundary coordinates.
i want a way to plot filled map of a region without storing their boundary coordinates on UI.
is their any way to plot a filled map of a region.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Can you provide code for what you have tried so far with geoJSOM? Also, check out the site [tour] and [ask] page to get some inspiration for how you can improve your question. Best of luck (: